# How to get array index of selected item from AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, position, autocompletetextview

I have a user data lie names etc. coming from database which is being populated to AutoCompleteTextView but the position in ItemCLickListener is of the position as displayed in the auto complete list.
I want the array index, and getting string from the adapter won't work because the same names can be there too.

**Update**

eg. In the database I have 4 entries abc, xyz, abc, pqrq along with some other data in other fields. These names are stored in an array.

So when I click abc, I want the other data to be fetched as well which could be done only if I know the array index of selected item.

Help!

Comment: can elobarate with en example

Comment: @Sush please check updated ques. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

1. Customise the auto_complete_tv_adapter for its items.
2. Adapter list items will be model wich will hold the name with others data.
3. Any selected item you will have data model with all other values handy.

sample : https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-autocompletetextview-custom-arrayadapter-sqlite/

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit new to android. How would I set the names in the list for the textview in custom adapter

Comment: use the sample link. that full fill your need, take look at how custom_adapter is getting created.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array of `Strings`, you should create an array with custom objects in it.

First, create a new `class` like this:

```
class CustomObject {

   public long id;
   public String name;

   public CustomObject(long id, String name) {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return name;
   }
}
```

Then, you get data from your database, which will be `Strings`, instead of storing only a `String` you can also add a **unique** id to  the array  which we will we use later.

So, for example, you can fill the array like this:

```
 // this array should contain the items from your database, and a unique id
 final CustomObject[] items = { new CustomObject(0, "test"), new CustomObject(1, "test"),
        new CustomObject(2123123, "another name")};
```

Then make your `AutoCompleteTextview` click detector look like this:

```
    textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CustomObject customObject = (CustomObject) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            int index = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].id == customObject.id) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // now we have your index :)
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your index = " + index,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

And that's it, there is the index you need. Note that for large arrays, this method will be slow.

Comment: How would I set the displayed string for AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: Which is `name`

Comment: I mean the adapter wouldn't be able to identify which item is to be displayed (id or name)

Comment: I am using arraylist instead of an array

Comment: Use `ArrayList<CustomObject>`

Comment: Yes, I have used custom object class not string. The problem is setting the display to name, whereas we have two variables in the class object.

Comment: Can you show me how you implemented it? I can help you on email.

Comment: what's your address?